# Read back an entered value as a sequence of numbers

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-connect

Withing the Get Customer Input of the Contact Flow, I am attempting to read back to the user, a 10-digit number.  However, it is reading it as a number, not a sequence of numbers.  By this I mean, it reads it back as "2 billion, 9 hundred and 64 million, 5 hundred and 12 thousand ...".  I just want it to be read back as "2 9 6 4 5 1 2 ..."

How do I get the Play Prompt to read it as a sequence of numbers?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, need to use SSML.  The text that is read back needs to be similar to this:

```
<speak>
    You entered <say-as interpret-as="digits">$.Attributes.SomeNumber</say-as> Is that correct? Press 1 for Yes and 2 for No.
</speak>
```

And set the type with the Get Customer Input to SSML.